# Errors coming up after moving items around on UserForms

Tags: vba, excel, compiler-errors

I have been formatting my UserForms to look better, essentially just resizing buttons and ListBoxes. After that this error began to show:

```
 System Error &H80004005 (-2147467259)
```

in an endless loop. When I killed the process the file also disappeared. I am working off a previous version now (pre-reformatting) but wonder what I might have done wrong. Any ideas what occurred?

Comment: If you deleted or changed the name of a control, that could cause this since VBA checks references to controls during compilation.

Comment: I deleted one button that I didn't want to use anymore, could that have caused it? If so, how do you avoid an error like that after deleting such a control?

Comment: Yes, that can cause it. You avoid it by ensuring you have no lingering references to deleted controls. You might also discover it without causing a crash by doing Debug->Compile VBAProject.

Comment: thanks. I will try that next time